# Using st_createDBSCAN for geography points

Tags: postgresql

I try to create clusters for geography points, but after many tries I still have only one cluster.
My points are geography and I convert it as text and then as geometry:

```
WITH ClusteredAccidents AS (
    SELECT 
        --a.*, 
        c."Location",      
        public.st_clusterdbscan(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(c."Location")) ,eps :=  500, minpoints := 2) OVER ( ) AS cid 
    FROM 
        acc."Accidents" a
    JOIN 
        acc."Coordinates" c ON a."Id" = c."AccidentId" 
    WHERE 
        a."RoadId" IN (SELECT "Id" FROM rds."Roads" WHERE "Ref" = 'D1' and "Id" =16768)
)
SELECT * FROM ClusteredAccidents ;
```

Comment: without tables and data, it is hard to figure out what is wrong

Comment: c."Location" column has geography points data, i see the problem that dbscan using only geometry and I transformed from geograhy to geometry.

Comment: The first 3 rows from table `code` POINT (16.42855772799 49.1964311769134)         0 
POINT (16.4284087566346 49.196652269795) 0
POINT (16.4189647237325 49.2069237495041) 0
POINT (16.4239437124783 49.1999524352414) 0  `code`

Comment: please add all new information to your question and don't post it in the comments, but still that isn't enough to help you we need all CREATE TABLE and data for all tables

Comment: `st_clusterdbscan` doesn't work with geography, only with geometries. If you just cast the geographies to geometries, the CRS is 4326 and the distance unit is in `degree`, so it is expected that all points on earth falls within the same cluster. You must transform your geographies to geometries using a suitable local projection whose distance unit is in meters.

Comment: @JGH Thanks for you answer, it is true when I use it I got one big claster becsue it works as geometry. But, I tried convert it and got same result: public.st_clusterdbscan(ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(c."Location",4326),3857) ,eps :=  50, minpoints := 3) OVER ( ) AS cid

Comment: This is not how you cast nor project to another coordinate system. Try `st_transform(c."Location"::geometry,3857)` (note that there is no need to write/read as text). That being said, 3857 is not a suitable local projection, as it highly distorts distances.

Comment: @JGH Thanks for answer , but it doesnt work (with distance as meters) , if I set eps=50, one claster, but if I chganed to 0.0005 (like degree)  I have 9 clusters